# Comment exprimer la même chose que « is defined as » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, mathématiques

Quelle est la façon la plus naturelle pour exprimer :

> (Le tenseur de déformation) X is defined as (suivi d'une équation de définition)

?

> 1. X est défini par
> 2. X se définit par
> 3. On définit X par

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Le tenseur de déformation de Cauchy noté `T` est défini par l'équation `T = ....`